# Union member has a non-trivial copy constructor

Tags: c++, string, constructor

I have a union that looks like this:

```
union {
  int intValue;
  double doubleValue;
  std::string stringValue;
  void *pointerValue;
} values;
```

When I compile it, I get this error message (yes, I did `#include <string>`):

```
./Value.hh:19:19: error: union member 'stringValue' has a non-trivial copy constructor                 
      std::string stringValue;                                                                         
                  ^                                                                                    
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk//usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_string.h:434:7: note: because         
      type 'std::basic_string<char>' has a user-declared copy constructor                              
      basic_string(const basic_string& __str);                                                         
      ^
```

I compile it using this command:

```
$ clang++ *.cc -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/ -shared
```

How can I use an `std::string` in a union?

Comment: You really probably don't want to use a union.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot.

A union combines two pieces of functionality: the ability to store an object which may be of a select number of types, and the ability to effectively (and implementation-defined) convert between those types. You could put an integer in and look at its representation as a double. And so forth.

Because a union must support *both* of these pieces of functionality (and for a few other reasons, like being able to construct one), a union prevents you from doing certain things. Namely, you cannot put "live" objects in them. Any object that is "living" enough that it needs a non-default copy constructor (among many other restrictions) cannot be a member of a union.

After all, a union object does not really have the concept of which type of data it actually stores. It does not store one type of data; it stores *all* of them, at the same time. It is up to you to be able to fish the right type out. So how could it reasonably copy one union value into another?

Members of a union must be a POD (plain-old-data) type. And while C++11 does loosen those rules, objects still must have a default (or otherwise trivial) copy constructor. And `std::string`'s copy constructor is non-trivial.

What you likely want is a [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html). That is an object that can store a number of possible types, just like a union. Unlike a union however, it is type-safe. It therefore knows what is actually in the union; it is therefore able to copy itself and otherwise behave like a regular C++ object.

Comment: Update: variant is part of the standard library since c++ 17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Answer (score 7):

You cannot put a `std::string` in a union. It is disallowed by the C++ language because it is unsafe. Consider that most `std::string` implementations have a pointer to some dynamic memory that holds the value of the string. Consider also that there is no way to know which union member is currently active.

An implementation cannot call the destructor of `std::string`, because it does not know that the `std::string` object is the currently active member, but if it does not call the destructor then memory will be leaked.

Comment: I believe in C++11 you are allowed to place types with non-trivial constructors/destructors in a union, but you must call them explicitly with placement new and t.~T() syntax. 9.5.3-9.5.4

Comment: Here is the example from `en.cppreference.com/`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Answer (score 4):

As per the C++ Standard §9.5.1:

*An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor, a non-trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial destructor, or a non-trivial copy assignment operator cannot be a member of a union.*

Hence, members of a union can't have constructors, destructors, virtual member functions, or base classes. Hence you cannot use std::string as an member of union.

**Alternative Solution:**

You can use **boost::variant** or **boost::any**.

Comment: Seems I need to investigate why I am able to put a class with a custom copy-assignment `operator=(T const &that)` into a `union` just fine... many times over. Was this restriction lifted in C++14, or is the `union` 'falling back' to another, implicit copy-assign, _e.g._ `operator=(T that)`?

Comment: ^ I believe the above was just the compiler not being strict enough with me. I now avoid that pattern: none of my `union` members have things they shouldn't. And they all still work great. :)

Comment: That paragraph is gone since C++11.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot use non-POD (plain old data) types in a union.
A fairly typical and simple workaround for this is to wrap the union in a struct,
and move the non-POD instance from inside the union to the struct.

For example:

```
struct Value {
    union {
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        void *pointerValue;
    };
    std::string stringValue;
};

Value value;

// Demonstration of accessing members:

value.intValue = 0;
value.doubleValue = 0.0;
value.pointerValue = NULL;
value.stringValue = "foo";
```

You do however pay a price for this - the memory footprint of the `Value` struct will be larger than that of the original union.

Answer (score 2):

`union` cannot have member of following types §9.5/1:

> An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects.

So either you define a pointer to std::string as:

```
union {
  int intValue;
  double doubleValue;
  std::string *stringValue; //pointer
  void *pointerValue;
} values;
```

or, use boost union which is known as [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: Would you mind having a look at my comment on Alok's answer (to avoid repeating myself) and letting me know any ideas?