# Why does C++ even care if I accessed both union members?

Tags: c++, c++17, unions

I wanted to have a struct that can be accessed both as an array and as named members. I wrote this:

```
struct RangeLimits
{
  enum class RangePenalty: byte
  {
    OUT_OF_RANGE,
    NO_PENALTY,
    SHORT,
    MEDIUM,
    LONG,
    EXTREME
  };
  union
  {
    struct
    {
      range shrt;
      range med;
      range lon;
      range ext;
    };
    std::array<range, 4> arang;
  };
};

namespace static_test
{

constexpr static bool checkThatArrayMapsToFields()
{
  RangeLimits limits{ range{1},range{1},range{1},range{1} };
  limits.med = range{ 66 };
  return limits.arang[1] == range{ 66 };
}

static_assert(checkThatArrayMapsToFields(), "Union not behaving as expected");
```

`range` is really just unsigned char. I am getting this error:

```
1>RangeLimits.h(41,41): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
1>RangeLimits.h(38,16): message : failure was caused by accessing a non-active member of a union
1>RangeLimits.h(38,16): message : see usage of 'techsheet::RangeLimits::arang'
```

I do understand this is how unions are supposed to behave in C++ (well, now I do anyway). But I do not understand why does C++ care, why this rule even exists. After all, you can't always check this anyway.

Comment: "range is really just unsigned char" > why not put it in your code snippet then?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933166/rationale-behind-active-members-of-unions).

Comment: ^^^ If not a dupe, I am tempted to close this. Accessing non active members is finally the same as using `reinterpret_cast` or c-style casts, and are explicitly stated as _undefined behavior_.

Comment: As for what to do instead: since you only want to provide different ways to access the *same* data, you should just use functions. Keep the array as your data storage, but provide access through, for example, `range& shrt() { return arang[0]; }`.